# PHP sql query and multiple WHERE's

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with autocomplete that filters on the idno, surname, reference and transno fields using $request from my index.php page.

Raceid is also passed from the index page to fetch.php to filter records (was originally in url on index.php page.

My sql query does not filter. It shows all the records. When i only use the "WHERE '$raceid' = raceid"  " part, then it filters 100%.

I cannot combine it with the code below it to get results.

How do i use two "WHERE's in the same sql query to filter the table?

Fetch.php

```
    <?php

$raceid = $_POST['raceid'];
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registerdb");
 $request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);


  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tblentries 
  WHERE '$raceid' = raceid
  AND WHERE idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
  ";

 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 $data =array();
 $html = '';
 $html .= '
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
     <th>No</th>
    <th>Id No</th>
    <th>Surnameame</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Transact No</th>
    <th>Total Fees</th>
    <th>Amount Pd</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
   </tr>
  ';
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $data[] = $row["raceid"];  
   $data[] = $row["idno"];
   $data[] = $row["surname"];
   $data[] = $row["firstname"];
   $data[] = $row["process"];
   $data[] = $row["reference"];
   $data[] = $row["transno"];
   $data[] = $row["total_fee"];
   $data[] = $row["amountpaid"];
   $data[] = $row["distance"];
   $html .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["raceid"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["idno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["surname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["process"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["reference"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["transno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["total_fee"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["amountpaid"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["distance"].'</td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $data = 'No Data Found';
  $html .= '
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">No Data Found</td>
   </tr>
   ';
 }
 $html .= '</table>';
 if(isset($_POST['typehead_search']))
 {
  echo $html;
 }
 else
 {
  $data = array_unique($data);
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't **re-declare** `WHERE`. In fact, you **can't** re-declare it.

In your following query:

```
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM tblentries 
  WHERE '$raceid' = raceid
  AND WHERE idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
  ";
```

Simply remove the second `WHERE`:

```
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM tblentries 
  WHERE '$raceid' = raceid
  AND idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
  ";
```

However, keep in mind the 'logic' of the above query; as it stands, the race ID will need to equal `raceid` **AND** the `idno` will need to equal the request... **OR** any of the other values need to match. That is to say, if your `OR` conditions trigger, you `raceid` doesn't need to! You probably want to make use of brackets to resolve this.

I've split the rows up a little further to clearly demonstrate this in the following example:

```
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tblentries 
  WHERE '$raceid' = raceid
  AND 
  (
  idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
  )
  ";
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: We should be seeing prepared statements here.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wrap your "OR" values in brackets, to keep it separate from the raceid check.

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM tblentries 
WHERE 
    '$raceid' = raceid
    AND 
    (
        idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
        OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
        OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
        OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
    )
";
```

Make sure you look into using prepared statements! Injecting $_POST['raceid'] directly into your query is going to cause you problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two mistakes in your query:

1. You are passing `$radeid` wrong

it should be `raceid = '".$raceid."'` e.g:

```
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tblentries 
  WHERE  raceid = ".$raceid."
  AND WHERE idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
  OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
  ";
```

2. You are using where twice, remove one where i.e

   ```
   $query = "
     SELECT * FROM tblentries 
     WHERE  raceid = ".$raceid."
     AND idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
     OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
     OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
     OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%'
     ";
   ```

Final query would be

```
 $query = "
          SELECT * FROM tblentries 
          WHERE  raceid = ".$raceid."
          AND (idno LIKE '%".$request."%' 
          OR surname LIKE '%".$request."%' 
          OR reference LIKE '%".$request."%' 
          OR transno LIKE '%".$request."%')
          ";
```

Comment: 1. The order does not matter.